# What analysis is appropriate for binary outcomes nested within individuals?

Tags: binary-data, nested-data

I'm working on my FYP & want to find out if my manipulation (condition: priming v.s. no priming) has any effect on distribution outcome (binary outcomes: 1-1 FAIR split; 2-0 UNFAIR split). Each individual went through 5 distribution trials and each trial was coded either fair or unfair.

I initially conducted a 2x2 chi square but my friend says that because my data is nested (5 trials; 5 distribution outcomes for each individual), chi -square isn't appropriate. If so, how should I analyze this data? I've read a little about using R to analyze nested data, but am totally unfamiliar with it, so would really appreciate any help :)

Thank you!!

Comment: So each person has 5 trials that they get right or wrong, is that correct?

Comment: Yup, 5 trials that are coded either fair (right) or unfair (wrong)

Comment: Should people be getting some of them right more than others? Eg, do the trials get progressively more difficult?

Comment: Each trial uses a different item. E.g. in the first trial, ppts distribute biscuits, in the second, stickers, and so on. It is possible that for trials with food items, ppts tend to distribute more fairly (get right more) and less fairly (get wrong more) for trials with non food items.

Comment: FYP?  Five year plan?

Comment: Final year project! :)